# How to remove CSS background image border

Tags: html, css, image, background

how can I remove the border that's surrounding the background image I tried border:none didn't didn't work I tried outline still nothing here's a link to the code: `"http://codepen.io/LightYagami116/pen/ezzYGW"` for whatever reason there's a white border around the top and left side of the image.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: I don't see any border, If you look image closely you can see there is some shadow effect on the image itself. crop it if you don't want to

Answer (score 1):

The image itself has a transparent white strip along the left and top: http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/8e457edf-9f1c-4db0-b6a2-128a5216076a5e1a2500-2ab6-4f28-a5dd-3b15ed5e96f0.jpg

Comment: lol ahh wow fell like such a noob lol did not notice that thanks

Answer (score 0):

HAve you tried using this rule?

```css
border: 0px solid #0000;
```

border: none should work, can you provide your source code?